Finite cardinals raised to the power of an infinite cardinal
I am trying to prove the fact that if $a$ and $b$ are finite cardinals, and $c$ is an infinite cardinal, then $a^c = b^c$.  I am able to prove this fact by using $d \cdot d = d$ for all infinite cardinals $d$, but I am looking for a direct proof that proves the existence of a one-one correspondence between functions from $C$ into $A$ and functions from $C$ into $B$.  This is trivial if $c$ is countably infinite, but I am having trouble if $c$ is uncountable.

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

Any infinite ordinal $\beta$ can be written uniquely as $\beta=\alpha+n$ (where we’re using ordinal addition), where $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal and $n \in \omega$.  Use that observation to reduce to the countable case.

Be careful, you must ensure that $a$ and $b$ are greater than $1$

Robert, I'm having trouble using your observation about infinite ordinals to reduce my problem to the countable case. Any hints?
